# I need to break a file into multiple files, seperating at specific points in the file

Tags: c#, file

Basically, I have huge files that should be many small ones. Within them there are lines that start with "O" which signify the beginning of a file and lines that "M" that signify the end.

What is the best way to make make sure that a program copies the "O" line and makes that the title of a new .txt file and then copies everything between (and including) the "O" and "M" lines and pastes that within the .txt file

The language doesn't matter too much I am just trying to figure out how I could go about this and I am having trouble - C# Novice here.

Comment: `I need a program` is not a valid question. SO is about helping people fixing problems related to code, not a code/program generator platform. If you have tried something, you're welcome to post your code and explain what problems you have.

Comment: I wasn't looking for someone to do the work for me, I was looking for guidance. Thanks for the feedback though I'll try to word my posts better in the future.
(See Stevens' great response)

Comment: So, basically, you have a task suitable for a junior developer or trainee and you come here asking for other people to write you a program doing what most people would consider quite easy string manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look into how to read a file in C#.
The static method `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` will help you here.

Then look into `String.Split` on how to split a very long string into seperate strings based on your own seperator.

Then look into creating different files, like here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file

EDIT: since you're talking about huge files, you could do an iterative approach and read line per line, or read a certain number of bytes. You can look at `File.ReadLine()` or you can parse character by character, like with `StreamReader.Read()` for instance. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=netframework-4.8) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time)

Comment: Definitely not. ReadAllText and hugh file means a LOT of memory wasted.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I was looking for

Comment: TomTom, if this is not a good way to go about it, i'd love actual input from you.

Comment: I updated my answer with two other possibilities.